# Bash - build URL query string by parsing script command arguments

Tags: bash

I don't use Bash very frequently but I need to work on a bit of Bash that has to make a curl request to a web service with a query string tail built from command arguments contained in the script command arguments variable `$@`.  So if the command argument string is something like `-e something -v -s somethingelse`, then the query string that must be produced is `e=something&v=blank&s=somethingelse`.

At the moment my test script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "${@}"

query_string=""
for arg in "${@}" ; do
  if [[ "${arg}" =~ "-" ]] ; then
    query_string+="${arg}="
  else
    if [ -z "${arg}" ] ; then
      query_string+="blank&"
    else
      query_string+="${arg}&"
    fi
  fi
done

echo "${query_string}" | tr -d '-'
```

and produces the incorrect output

```
e=something&v=s=somethingelse&
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "${@}"

option=true
query_string=""
for arg in "${@}" ; do
  if $option ; then
    query_string+="${arg}="
    option=false
  else
    if [[ "${arg}" =~ "-" ]] ; then
      query_string+="blank&${arg}="
    else
      query_string+="${arg}&"
      option=true
    fi
  fi
done

echo "${query_string::-1}" | tr -d '-'
```

Answer (score 1):

Every iteration you have to check the previous arg to see if it was a switch, not a value:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "${@}"

prev_arg=""
query_string=""
for arg in "${@}" ; do
  if [[ $arg == -* ]] ; then

    # Current arg is a switch and the previous one was also a switch 
    # which means the value for it is blank
    if [[ $prev_arg == -* ]] ; then
      query_string+="blank&"
    fi

    query_string+="${arg}="
  else
    query_string+="${arg}&"
  fi

  prev_arg="$arg"
done

echo "${query_string::-1}" | tr -d '-'
```

This produces the following output:

```
something -v -s somethingelse
e=something&v=blank&s=somethingelse
```

Comment: This is what I missed in mine :) to keep in mind the previous arg/opt.